# cakePHP show a validation error beside a label element in a view

Tags: validation, cakephp

Hello I have the following model :

```
class Mymodel extends AppModel {
    public $validate = array(
        'username' => array(
            'required' => array(
                'rule' => array('notEmpty'),
                'message' => 'A username is required'
            ),
            'regexp' => array(
                'rule' => '/^[a-z0-9]{3,10}$/i',
                'message' => 'Only letters and integers, min 3, max. 10 characters'
            )
        )
    )
}
```

and the following view : signup.ctp

```
<?php 
echo $this->Form->create("Mymodel ");  
echo $this->Form->input('username' ,array('label'=>"Username :")); 
echo $this->Form->input('password' ,array('label'=>"Password :",'type' => 'password')); 
echo $this->Form->end('signup'); 
?>
```

My controller is :

```
class MymodelController extends AppController
{
    public function signup()
    {}
}
```

The cakePHP default validation behaviour is to show the error messages below the input, so my question is : how can I show the errors in the label field I mean like this :

Username :(I want to show the error message here)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `$this->Form->error('fieldname')` to output the error message wherever you want (giving the input a parameter of `'error'=>false` to prevent it outputting the error message in the default position.

For example:-

```
$error = $this->Form->isFieldError('username') ? $this->Form->error('username') : '';
echo $this->Form->label('username', "Username : $error");
echo $this->Form->input('username' ,array('label' => false, 'error' => false));
```

Answer (score 1):

### Change the order of elements via the 'format' option

If it's okay to have the error-message put between the label and the input, change the order of the 'elements' of the input via the [`format`](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/helpers/form.html#options) option;

```
// Create the form. By setting options via the
// 'inputDefaults' option, the options are
// automatically applied to all inputs.
// of course, you can also set this option
// for each input individually
echo $this->Form->create("Mymodel", array(
    'inputDefaults' => array(
        // set the order of the 'elements' inside the input-div
        'format' => array('before', 'label', 'error', 'between', 'input', 'after'),
        // puts ':' between the label and the input
        'between' => ':',
    )
));  
echo $this->Form->input('username'); 
echo $this->Form->input('password'); 
echo $this->Form->end('signup');
```

#### note

I also added some extra modifications;

- the 'between' option can be used to add additional content to your input, for example (see the code) to put a `:` between the label and the input. Doing this, you don't have to set custom labels
- if an input is for a field named 'password', CakePHP will automatically create a password field. You don't have to set the type yourself (unless you want to override the type to something other than a 'password' input

Answer (score 0):

The form template is inside cake core libraries, and I wouldn't recommend changing any of those.

If you want to keep using

```
 echo $this->Form->input('username' ,array('label'=>"Username :"));
```

as always, instead of manually adding labels with errors, you have to do it with javascript.
The following is a bit of code in jquery that can achieve what you want

```
$(function() {
    $('.error-message').each( function(index) {
       var errorText = $(this).text();
       var label = $(this).siblings('label');
       label.text(label.text() + errorText);
       $(this).remove();
    });
});
```

Be sure to test it in case I missed something. Modify it to your needs, add some styling, etc.
If you want to do this *everywhere*, insert the script in the layout, otherwise add it to the views you want.